# using numpy array of arrays in Cython parallel with nogil

Tags: parallel-processing, cython, gil, cythonize

I want to assign numpy array of arrays (array with elements as array) inside Cython parallel loop with nogil. I use the dtype as an object to be able to assign the numpy array as an array element. It works in Cython without parallelizing. But by using parallel, it gives this error message:

> Assignment of Python object not allowed without gil

I did try different ways to declare that in cdef, but its still not working. I am not sure if Cython parallelizing supports array of arrays or not. If so, what would be the best way to declare the type and assign the value.

```
cdef np.ndarray[ dtype= object, ndim=2]  ST_matrix=np.zeros( 10, dtype=   [('f1', '(4,)float64'), ('f2', '(4,)float64')])
```

error message:

> Assignment of Python object not allowed without gil

```
cdef double [:,:] ST_matrix
ST_matrix=np.zeros( I, dtype=[('f1', '(4,)float64'), ('f2', '(4,)float64')])
```

error message:

> "Cannot assign type 'double[:]' to 'double' "

Comment: You aren't going to be able to use anything with `dtype=object` in a `nogil` block. I don't think you can call Python functions (e.g. `np.zeros`) in a `nogil` block. Unfortunately this may be something that just won't work in parallel. _However_ if it's only one line that's causing you problems but that line in a `with gil:` block.